Trying to understand kube_cronjob_status_active and other k8s metrics
I am trying to leverage the kubernetes provided metrics to monitor my cronjob running in k8s cluster, one of the metric I want to use is kube_cronjob_status_active, from what I learned from doc this metric means if cronjob is active, by active my understanding is the cronjob's job instance is running. However this metric confuses me since it shows different result when comparing with other metrics.
For example:
In the given time window, kube_cronjob_status_active{cronjob=my-job} shows that there is no active cronjob running:

However if I check kube_job_status_start_time{job_name=my-job*} (my-job is a cronjob, every job instance has name like my-job-12345678) within same time window, it shows that there are jobs scheduled to run approximately every 5 minutes:

So how should I understand the kube_cronjob_status_active? Thanks
